# Generate Linq query in c# function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq in C#.
I have defined my own function like this

```
public static void AutoSuggest(TextBox t, string columnName, string tableName)
{

}
```

- t is the refrence of the textbox
- ColumnName is the Name of specific column
- Tablename is the name of specific table

In this user defined function, using the parameters, I want to get the specified column data from the specified table of the database.

So, how should I generate this query in Linq?

Comment: Please, first try yourself.....If you get error,then specify the error....

Comment: which specific row is the value in?

Comment: Have you made a database model?

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to use LINQ, you would be better talking about a source and selector; some `IQueryable<T>` and something like `Expression<Func<T,string>>`. If you want to use column/table names, firstly they **must** be white-listed (don't ever accept the names from, say, a web-request), but the code would be simply:

```
var values = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<string>("select distinct [" + columnName
      + "] from [" + tableName +"]").ToList();
```

this is a pretty naive approach, but it shows basic usage; then you would data-bind as normal. However, I'd be much more inclined for the calling code just to do, for example:

```
var values = dataContext.SomeTable.Select(x => x.SomeProperty)
              .Distinct().ToList();
```

which would avoid risk of injection etc.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor you can't use parameters for the table/column names